# Maintain Aspect Ration on SVG Image Calculation Formula

Tags: image, html, svg, aspect-ratio

I have an image element of the SVG inb the HTML5,

The image size is: 
(stretch, preserveAspectRatio is set to "none")
width=520px
height=240px

then, I modify it to maintain aspect ratio (preserveAspectRatio is set to defer)
because width>height,
the height still the same = 240px
but how can I calculate the new width (it is shrinked because the maintain aspect ratio)
is there a formula to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

viewBox width / viewBox height * 240px I imagine.

Comment: apparently your formula is right, and with that I have to load the image again from Image of HTML5 to get the original size of the image then to calculate the new width of the image of the SVG